# CMake error with AVR WINAVR compiler

Tags: windows, cmake, avr, avr-gcc, winavr

```
The C compiler identification is GNU
The CXX compiler identification is GNU
Check for working C compiler: C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe" is not able to compile
  a simple test program.
```

It fails with the following output:

```
   Change Dir: F:/projects/UniRobot/code/navigation/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~1/CMAKE2~1.8/bin/cmake.exe
  "cmTryCompileExec/fast"

  CMake Error: The source directory
  "F:/projects/UniRobot/code/navigation/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec/fast"
  does not exist.

  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (PROJECT)
```

So, Everything is ok under Linux and Win 7, but under XP SP2,SP3 i have this error. It  means that my AVR compiler for controllers is incorrect  and CMake can't provide test program using WINAVR compiler. For the first time running this error was under Win7 too, but after the second running it disapperared. I wrote paths in windows reg. I rewrote paths to compilers, sh and cmake. But the error still take a place.

Comment: could you please provide the CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log ? also I think following link could help to analyze your issue http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-06/msg00026.html

Comment: Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: F:/projects/UniRobot/code/navigation/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~1/CMAKE2~1.8/bin/cmake.exe "cmTryCompileExec/fast"
CMake Error: The source directory "F:/projects/UniRobot/code/navigation/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec/fast" does not exist.

Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: to use cross compiler on host system it is required to define toolchain file and provide it to cmake as per http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling . for example "cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path to Toolchain-eldk-ppc8xx.cmake> ..

Answer (score 0):

The Compiller C and C++ is already written in CMake cross compile file. How i did this you can see here http://robot-develop.org/archives/2952

On another machine with Win Vista and 7 everything are OK.

I tried to choose manually C|C++ compiler files AVR-GCC and AVR-G++ from WINAVR directory, but the error still take place.